# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) [Evaluate on validation data and plot results]

Tags: python, machine-learning

The problem I'm currently facing is at the `raw_predictions, x = best_tft.predict(val_dataloader, mode="raw", return_x=True)` I want to make a raw prediction using TFT but instead got a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

```
 actuals = torch.cat([y[0] for x, y in iter(val_dataloader)]).to(device)
 predictions = best_tft.predict(val_dataloader)

 #average p50 loss overall
 print((actuals - predictions).abs().mean().item())
 #average p50 loss per time series
 print((actuals - predictions).abs().mean(axis=1))


 INFO: LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
 INFO:lightning.pytorch.accelerators.cuda:LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
 6.585674285888672
 tensor([ 1.2201,  7.6303,  2.1221,  8.3330, 13.6227], device='cuda:0')




 raw_predictions, x = best_tft.predict(val_dataloader, mode="raw", return_x=True)

 for idx in range(5):  # plot all 5 consumers
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
     best_tft.plot_prediction(x, raw_predictions, idx=idx, add_loss_to_title=True,ax=ax)

 INFO: LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
 INFO:lightning.pytorch.accelerators.cuda:LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]
```

Error:

```
     ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-53-be332321242d> in <cell line: 1>()
     ----> 1 raw_predictions, x = best_tft.predict(val_dataloader, mode="raw", return_x=True)
           2 
           3 for idx in range(5):  # plot all 5 consumers
           4     fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
           5     best_tft.plot_prediction(x, raw_predictions, idx=idx, add_loss_to_title=True,ax=ax)

     ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

How to fix it?